# flutter doctor command not responding

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, dart

i am using linux ubunto :

[image: ubunto version]

this is output of "echo $PATH":

[image: echo $PATH]

when i type "flutter doctor", the terminal goes to next line stuck at this point...like i should be writing more...

"flutter doctor":

[image: flutter doctor]

what am i missing here to get flutter command working ?!

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install flutter SDK, worked for me.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.